# Trouble mapping an array to JSX - Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I am having trouble mapping an `employees` array to a new array using ReactJS and JSX. **Something is going on with my return method**. Note: Extreme beginner to React and ES6.

How do I get this to work?

Here's my code: [**[live version on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/doss1/vfp2g34v/2/)**]

```
class EmployeesTable extends React.Component {
  render() {

const employees = [{
  name: 'John',
  age: 34
}, {
  name: 'Mary',
  age: 23
}, {
  name: 'Tom',
  age: 100
}];

    return ({
      employees.map(employee => { <ul>
          <li> {
            employee.name
          } </li> </ul>
      });
    });

  }
};

class Directory extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( < section >
      < h1 > Hello World < /h1> < EmployeesTable / >
      < /section>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render( <Directory / > , document.getElementById('directory'));
```

Comment: fixed fiddle link to latest version

Comment: Example https://jsfiddle.net/vfp2g34v/3/

Comment: `return ({...});` means that an *object* should be returned (`{...}` is an object literal. You cannot put arbitrary function calls inside an object literal (i.e. `({ foo() })` is invalid). That has nothing to do with JSX.

Answer (score 0):

```
   return  (<div>
      {employees.map(employee => ( 
         <ul>
          <li> {employee.name  } </li> 
        </ul>
       )
    )}
    </div>
   )
```

Not

```
   return ({
      employees.map(employee => { <ul>
          <li> {
            employee.name
          } </li> </ul>
      });
    });
```

```js
class EmployeesTable extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let employees = [{
  name: 'John',
  age: 34
}, {
  name: 'Mary',
  age: 23
}, {
  name: 'Tom',
  age: 100
}];

    employees = employees.map((employee, index) => (
     <ul key={index}><li >{ employee.name }</li><li>{employee.age}</li></ul>
    ));
    return (<div>{employees}</div>);
  
  
 }
};

class Directory extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <section>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <EmployeesTable />
      </section>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
 <Directory  /> , 
  document.getElementById('directory')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<aside id="directory"></aside>
```

Comment: More of that you need to ES6 preset

Comment: Please check the code snippet below the answer. Thank you.

Comment: The render function of an React component must return an element, it cannot return an array.

Comment: @FelixKling:  i put it in code snippet and miss it there. thank you for the note